# Get key value from nested dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have class with a nested dictionary data object. I need to get all the key values from it. What's the best efficient way to do this?

I'm stuck with following:

```
for k,v in data.items():
    print v.keys()
```

This is the data:

```
data = {
    "BANK": {
        "no_data": "INT",
    },
    "SHOCK": {
        "drop": "NOTI",
        "rise": "NOTI",
        "high_risk": "ALERT",
    },
    "OFFLINE": {"online": None, "offline_few": "ALERT"},
}
```

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Answer (score 3):

An elegant way to concatenate lists (your `value.keys()` lists) into one is using a double-loop list comprehenstion, like this:

```
nested_keys = [
    key
    for val in data.values()
    for key in val.keys()]
```

Comment: This would get *keys of the values dictionaries* only. This wouldn't get `"BANK,"SHOCK","OFFLINE"`. OP's question is vague though.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator:

```
def all_keys(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield k
        # assume that anything with `items` property will be a mapping
        # this can be replaced with: `isinstance(v, dict)` or `isinstance(v, collections.Mapping)`
        if hasattr(v, 'items'):  
            yield from all_keys(v)
```

On your input this produces:

```
data = {
    "BANK": {
        "no_data": "INT",
    },
    "SHOCK": {
        "drop": "NOTI",
        "rise": "NOTI",
        "high_risk": "ALERT",
    },
    "OFFLINE": {"online": None, "offline_few": "ALERT"},
}
print(list(all_keys(data)))
# ['BANK', 'no_data', 'SHOCK', 'drop', 'rise', 'high_risk', 'OFFLINE', 'online', 'offline_few']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Recursive Function**

Gets all keys at all levels of nested dictionary

```
def get_keys(d, result = None): 
  # use default of None to fix issue noted by @Ch3steR
  # namely: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm
  if result is None:
    result = []

  for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        result.append(k)
        get_keys(v, result)
    else:
      result.append(k)

  return result
```

**Test**

```
print(get_keys(data))
```

*Output*

```
['BANK', 'no_data', 'SHOCK', 'drop', 'rise', 'high_risk', 'OFFLINE', 'online', 'offline_few']
```

Comment: You will encounter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: You can check it yourself run the function twice. After calling it once `get_keys.__defaults__` will be `(['BANK',
  'no_data',
  'SHOCK',
  'drop',
  'rise',
  'high_risk',
  'OFFLINE',
  'online',
  'offline_few'],)` after second time `get_keys.__defaults__` will be `(['BANK',
 'no_data',
 'SHOCK',
 'drop',
 'rise',
 'high_risk',
 'OFFLINE',
 'online',
 'offline_few',
 'BANK',
 'no_data',
 'SHOCK',
 'drop',
 'rise',
 'high_risk',
 'OFFLINE',
 'online',
 'offline_few'])`

Comment: Here's [link](https://repl.it/repls/RelievedInfatuatedArchitect) to check.

Comment: @Ch3steR, my solution will not have this issue, probably; could you check?

Comment: @PiyushSingh If you have a mutable default parameter don't mutate it in-place. Just run it twice or thrice and use `func.__defaults__` will you get to know.

Comment: @PiyushSingh Checked your function it encountered the same [least astonishment and mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) issue

Comment: @Ch3steR--thanks for the reminder and updated post to set default param on call.

Answer (score 0):

If all your "actual" key-value pairs are at a certain depth, for example for depth 1, you can go like:

```
data = {
    "BANK": {
        "no_data": "INT",
    },
    "SHOCK": {
        "drop": "NOTI",
        "rise": "NOTI",
        "high_risk": "ALERT",
    },
    "OFFLINE": {"online": None, "offline_few": "ALERT"},
}
dic = {k:v for val in data.values() for k,v in val.items()}
```

But if you dont know that:

```
data = {
    "BANK": {
        "no_data": "INT",
    },
    "SHOCK": {
        "drop": "NOTI",
        "rise": "NOTI",
        "high_risk": "ALERT",
    },
    "online": None, 
    "offline_few": "ALERT"
}
```

In this case you need to use recursion:

```
def unnest(dic, final=dict()):
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if not isinstance(val, dict):
            final[key] = val
        else:
            dic2 = dict()
            for k, v in val.items():
                dic2[k] = v
            unnest(dic2, final)
    return final    

dic = unnest(data, {}) #every use of the function should have {} to solve issue pointed by @Ch3steR
```

In any case, once you have the "un-nested" dictionary it is trivial to print out the keys:

```
print(dic.keys())
```

Comment: Check your function it will encounter [least astonishment and mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). To check if it does do `unnest.__defaults__`

Comment: @Ch3steR, thanks for sharing that. I didnt know such a thing existed in python. Updated my answer to solve the issue, I just had to make sure that each time the function is called it starts with a fresh empty dictionary.

Comment: @Ch3steR, here is a piece of code that shows then solves the issue:
https://repl.it/repls/UselessWorseNewsaggregator

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NestedDict`. First install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts)

```
pip install ndicts
```

Then

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict
data = {
    "BANK": {
        "no_data": "INT",
    },
    "SHOCK": {
        "drop": "NOTI",
        "rise": "NOTI",
        "high_risk": "ALERT",
    },
    "OFFLINE": {"online": None, "offline_few": "ALERT"},
}
nd = NestedDict(data)
```

The result

```
>>> list(nd.keys())
[('BANK', 'no_data'), ('SHOCK', 'drop'), ('SHOCK', 'rise'), ('SHOCK', 'high_risk'), ('OFFLINE', 'online'), ('OFFLINE', 'offline_few')]
```